# How to use tf.gather_nd to slice a tensor in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am looking for the tensorflow equivalent of the following code in numpy. `a` and `idx_2` are given. The goal is to construct `b`.

```
# A float Tensor obtained somehow
a = np.arange(3*5).reshape(3,5)                    

# An int Tensor obtained somehow
idx_2 = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[0,2,3,4],[0,2,3,4]])  

# An int Tensor, constructed for indexing
idx_1 = np.arange(a.shape[0]).reshape(-1,1)        

# The goal
b = a[idx_1, idx_2]

print(b)
>>> [[ 1  2  3  4]
     [ 5  7  8  9]
     [10 12 13 14]]
```

I have tried directly indexing the tensors and using `tf.gather_nd` but I keep getting errors so I decided to ask how to do it here. Everywhere I look for answers people use `tf.gather_nd` (hence the title) to solve similar problems, but to apply this functions I have to somehow reshape the indexes such that they can be used to slice the first dimension. How do I do this? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tensorflow can be quite ugly when it comes to things that are very simple and Pythonic in NumPy. Here is how I used tf.gather_nd to recreate your problem in TensorFlow. There is probably a much better way to do it though.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Define 'a'
    a = tf.reshape(tf.range(15),(3,5))
    # Define both index tensors 
    idx_1 = tf.reshape(tf.range(a.get_shape().as_list()[0]),(-1,1)).eval()
    idx_2 = tf.constant([[1,2,3,4],[0,2,3,4],[0,2,3,4]]).eval()
    # get indices for use with gather_nd
    gather_idx = tf.constant([(x[0],y) for (i,x) in enumerate(idx_1) for y in idx_2[i]])
    # extract elements and reshape to desired dimensions
    b = tf.gather_nd(a, gather_idx)
    b = tf.reshape(b,(idx_1.shape[0], idx_2.shape[1]))
    print(sess.run(b))

[[ 1  2  3  4]
[ 5  7  8  9]
[10 12 13 14]]
```