# Highlight specific coordinates on multiple zero matrices using only vectorized operations

Tags: python, tensorflow, matrix

Let's say there are `2` `5x5` sparse matrices stacked on each other (or `tf.zeros(2, 5, 5)`).

Then suppose there also is an array of coordinates `[[0, 2, 4, 4], [2, 0, 3, 3]]`, which respectively shows starting width position, starting height position, ending width position, and ending height position of coordinates (i.e `[starting_w, starting_h, ending_w, ending_h]` for each coordinate).

I want to "highlight" the `(2, 5, 5)` sparse shape accordng to the coordinates mentioned above, so that on each sparse matrix of shape, each coordinate is respectively "projected" and there are `1`s on those coordinates and `0`s anywhere else.

## Example

So as mentioned earlier, we have a `(2, 5, 5)` sparse shape:

```
[[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]

 [[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]]
```

Now we "project" each coordinate out of `[[0, 2, 4, 4], [2, 0, 3, 3]]` on each sparse matrix:

```
[[[1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]  # [0, 2, 4, 4]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]

 [[1. 0. 1. 1. 0.]  # [2, 0, 3, 3]
  [1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]]
```

**Note:**

The example seen above uses `n = 2` coordinates, and thus generates `2` matrices, but in general `n` must be treated as a symbolic tensor which can have any value.

## Question

Can something like this be done on pure vectorized operations of highly declarative Tensorflow? (without any use of operations like `tf.map_fn`, `tf.while` and etc.).

**What I tried:**

I've initially tried [tf.gather_nd](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather_nd), but it doesn't explicitly support slices (although there are [some "hacks"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53686871/6083655) which fail to work due to absence of symbolic support). I know [tf.slice](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/slice) is meant to precisely do that, but it does not have explicit support of example demonstrated above.

I also thought of using `tf.where`, which might easily work on single array with single coordinate - but I don't know if it supports multiple ones as demonstrated above.

Thank you!

Comment: So you want to get ones in a slice of the first row and the first column? Not on the actual "window" defined in each matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make that result like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def make_highlights(idx, width, height, dtype=tf.bool):
    n = tf.shape(idx)[0]
    # Add two dimensions for broadcasting later
    idx = idx[:, :, np.newaxis, np.newaxis]
    # Extract coordinates
    start_w, start_h, end_w, end_h = idx[:, 0], idx[:, 1], idx[:, 2], idx[:, 3]
    # Make index arrays
    xx = tf.range(width)
    yy = tf.expand_dims(tf.range(height), 1)
    # Make first row highlighting
    h_x = tf.equal(yy, 0) & (xx > start_w) & (xx <= end_w)
    # Make first column highlighting
    h_y = tf.equal(xx, 0) & (yy >= start_h) & (yy <= end_h)
    # Make result
    return tf.cast(h_x | h_y, dtype)

with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
    idx = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, 4])
    width = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [])
    height = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [])
    result = make_highlights(idx, width, height, tf.float32)
    out = sess.run(result, feed_dict={idx: [[0, 2, 4, 4], [2, 0, 3, 3]],
                                      width: 5, height: 5})
    print(out)
    # [[[1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
    #   [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
    #   [1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
    #   [1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
    #   [1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
    # 
    #  [[1. 0. 1. 1. 0.]
    #   [1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
    #   [1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
    #   [1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
    #   [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and I apologize for being implicit with my question. Your code works perfectly for this specific example seen in the question, but I'm looking for generalization of it, i.e in cases where there are symbolically defined amounts of coordinates (columns/rows) to be projected on zero matrices. Obviously number of zero matrices must be equal to number of coordinates, but this number should be assumed to be a symbolic tensor. Is this dynamic generalization possible?

Comment: @ShellRox I'm not sure I understand. In the code I posted, if you add another row of four numbers to the value passed to `idx` you will get a third matrix in the result.

Comment: I heavily apologize for misunderstanding, I didn't read the code properly - it actually works perfectly for all coordinates. Thank you very much for the great solution and explanation!